# Why do Devise registration params sometimes have a different form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a slightly customized Devise integration with a Rails 5 app. I'm inheriting from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and implementing my own `create` action for a `User` resource, and not calling `super`.

All of the time in development, and most of the time in production, `params` from the form come through like this:

```ruby
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"***",
  "user"=> {
    "email"=>"foo@example.com",
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"
  },
  "commit"=>"Create account"
}
```

But a minority of the time, in production only, `params` looks like this:

```ruby
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"***",
  "user[email]"=>"foo@example.com",
  "user[password]"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "user[password_confirmation]"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "commit"=>"Create account",
  "registration"=> {
    "user[email]"=>"foo@example.com",
    "user[password]"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "user[password_confirmation]"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "commit"=>"Create account"
  }
}
```

I don't know why this second form of the parameters appears. My assumption is that under some circumstances Devise processes the parameters differently. The only case I could think of to examine was re-submitting after a validation problem, and every time I try this the params still come through in the first form (in development and production).

The `create` action was written with the assumption that `params[:user]` has a hash of user attributes, which isn't the case for this second form. I can handle the two forms of these parameters, but I would like to understand why this happens and I do not want this action to be called with randomly different params.

In case it's relevant, the submission form (with styling classes omitted):

```html
  <%= form_for(@user, as: :user, url: registration_path(:user)) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Password confirmation' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <%= f.submit "Create account" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Edited with an update. Additional logging has confirmed something interesting: the `request.media_type` for the bugged requests is `application/json` (where for typical requests it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

---

Edited with update. It looks to me like the form data is being submitted with the wrong request type, this might explain both why values aren't being unpacked (why we have `user[email]` as an attribute name in the params) and why we're getting the params wrapped in that `registration` object (I have wrap_parameters enabled for JSON).

What this doesn't explain is why only some requests are getting tagged with this media type.

Final Edit: after observing my logs for a time I conclude that this issue is being caused by bots. The failures always occur as part of 3 requests from the same IP, with only the last having JSON data, all within a few seconds. The bot is just reading the form and converting it to JSON in a way that doesn't make sense for Rails. Thank you to the folks who took a look at this.

Comment: are you doing anything with turbo (frame/streams) in your registration page?

Comment: Nope, no turbolinks in this app @MarianTheisen.

Comment: Misunderstood this to start. No, I'm not using Turbo either!

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the [`ActionController::ParamsWrapper`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) kicks in.

When enabled, the params wrapper wraps incoming parameters with the current controller's name when not already nested under that name.

In your example, you are sending parameters nested under `user` to a controller named `RegistrationsController`. Therefore, the ParamsWrapper wraps them with `registration` again. If you had sent them to a `UsersController` they would not be changes, because they are already nested under `user`.

---

IMHO, this is one of Ruby on Rails' most useless and error-prone magic behavior. And I usually disable it right away, because it often leads to issues. For example, when the frontend doesn't do any nesting and just depends on this feature, but the backend needs to restructure and introduce namespaces or rename controllers.

Comment: I've investigated the parameter wrapper, and it's only enabled for JSON formatted requests (e.g. `wrap_parameters format: [:json]`). After some additional logging I've confirmed that this issue turns up with form submissions with HTML format, and we don't submit requests for JSON. Also... why would the wrapping code fire only some of the time? And why are the user attributes still "packed" (e.g. with keys like `user[email]`) in the second form?